# Excel VBA Conditional Formatting Blank Cells in Row

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

Right off the bat, I am a total novice at coding, and the extent of my skill is modifying based on Google searches.

I am using Excel 2010, and trying to use VBA to avoid using conditional formatting.  The spreadsheet I'm using is a template with 31 columns, 20 of which are mandatory.  There is coding in place that if there is an entry in one of these columns for any given row, the other 19 cells must be populated before the file can be saved.

I'm trying to do a similar function to highlight the blank cells preventing the file from being saved.  I know that I could use the conditional formatting, but that would require it to look at one cell in each row, as opposed to any of the required cells in that row.  I also know that it could do multiple conditional formats, but I know the more layers there are, the slower the spreadsheet will function.

Is this possible?  The columns I have that are mandatory are A-D, F-K, M-N, S-Y & AE.  In case it would be a factor, I have attached the code I'm using to mandate entry once any of those columns are populated:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rg As Range, c As Range
    Dim bCanSave As Boolean
    Dim sWarning As String

    Set ws = Sheets("Main")
    Set rg = ws.Range("A2:A10000,B2:B10000,C2:C10000,D2:D10000,F2:F10000,G2:G10000,H2:H10000,J2:J10000,K2:K10000,N2:N10000,S2:S10000,T2:T10000,U2:U10000,V2:V10000,W2:W10000,X2:X10000,Y2:Y10000,AE2:AE10000")
    sWarning = "File not saved!" & vbNewLine & "Mandatory cells missing in rows: " & vbNewLine

    With ws
        bCanSave = True
        For Each c In rg
            If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
                If .Cells(c.Row, "A") = "" Or .Cells(c.Row, "B") = "" Or .Cells(c.Row, "C") = "" Or .Cells(c.Row, "D") = "" Or .Cells(c.Row, "F") = "" Or .Cells(c.Row, "G") = "" Or .Cells(c.Row, "H") = "" Or .Cells(c.Row, "I") = "" Or .Cells(c.Row, "J") = "" Or .Cells(c.Row, "K") = "" Or .Cells(c.Row, "N") = "" Or .Cells(c.Row, "S") = "" Or .Cells(c.Row, "T") = "" Or .Cells(c.Row, "U") = "" Or .Cells(c.Row, "V") = "" Or .Cells(c.Row, "W") = "" Or .Cells(c.Row, "X") = "" Or .Cells(c.Row, "Y") = "" Or .Cells(c.Row, "AE") = "" Then
                    bCanSave = False
                    sWarning = sWarning & c.Row & ","
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    End With

    If Not bCanSave Then
        MsgBox sWarning, vbExclamation
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: "I am using Excel _____" - is that "____" a placeholder for the year/version?

Comment: Mat's Mug: Yes...edited the OP with Excel 2010.
pnuts: Maybe poor wording on my part?  If I want to impact conditional formatting on 20 columns, I would need to have 20 dependent conditions.

Comment: Just for the cf-part: If you do the conditional formatting for a range like `$A$1:$D$100,$F$1:$K$100,$M$1:$N$100,$S$1:$Y$100,$AE$1:$AE$100` and with the setting `Format only cells that contain` -> `specific text` & `not containing` & `*` you will get this super fast... each cell will only be checked if changed -> no slowdown (at least: nothing a human being is able to notice) :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Const CHECK_RNG As String = "A1:D1,F1:K1,M1:M1,S1:Y1,AE1"
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim bCanSave As Boolean, sep As String
    Dim sWarning As String, sMissing As String, r As Long, ct As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Main")

    sWarning = "File not saved!" & vbNewLine & "Mandatory cells missing in rows: " & vbNewLine
    bCanSave = True

    For r = 2 To 10000
        Set rg = ws.Rows(r).Range(CHECK_RNG)
        rg.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone '<< clear any previous fill
        ct = Application.CountA(rg)
        If ct > 0 And ct <> rg.Cells.Count Then
            rg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.Color = vbYellow '<< fill empty
            bCanSave = False
            sMissing = sMissing & sep & r
            sep = ","
        End If
    Next r

    If Not bCanSave Then
        MsgBox sWarning & sMissing, vbExclamation
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This is only cleaning up my existing code, which I appreciate.  My unskilled attempt at writing myself gave me a pretty worthless error message.  (My original code prior to this request worked, but I removed a dependency that gave me repeated errors for each row missing data).

I am still hoping to use VBA to highlight the cells with no data though.

Comment: Amazing.  Thank you.

Stupid question, but I'm guessing it's the limitation of the coding.  Any color formatting after-the-fact gets wiped out when saving; the code runs and the "rg.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone" clears it out.  Anyway around this?

Thanks again.

Comment: If you don't clear the fill then "fixed" rows still show up as "problem" rows. 
 Otherwise it's not obvious how you'd distinguish between "wanted" fill and "unwanted" fill ?

Comment: ...if you want to highlight empty cells without interfering with existing fills then consider adding the highlight as a Conditional Format: this will override  any existing cell color, but the color will revert back when you remove the CF.

Comment: Ok, I think I just may want something that VBA can't do.  I understand your follow up between wanted & unwanted fill; with the various drop downs or column formatting, I don't think there is much concern about unwanted fill.  I know that losing the ability to color code after the cells are populated is going to create heartburn for other users, so I may be stuck.

The two reasons I didn't want to use CF was 1) that removing rows alters the range, and 2) that I didn't want to have to rely on looking at the relation between two cells to dictate the CF.

Comment: You can apply and remove the CF from the macro: will there be any other CF on that range?

Comment: I'm back at this code for a new criteria.  I had column M as a required row, and my users are trying to stipulate a specific combination of two other columns as to when it would not be required.  
In the attempt to simplify this, I'm looking to achieve the exact same results of the code you posted in August, except column M is not required if column G = "Alpha" and column J = "Bravo".  Is this feasible?  Thanks

Comment: And already one more criteria apparently...
I also need to avoid requiring input in column M if the last four characters in column H are "abcd".  I would know how to target the last four characters through formulas, but not in VBA.  Thanks again for all your help.